# How to recursively build a package and its dependencies on a Debian-based system?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dependencies, apt-get, portage

Basically I want

1. `apt-get`'s dependency resolving ability, and
2. to compile packages with customized options (such as the loader path).

Can that be done with the `apt-*` suite? If not, perhaps I can try to set up Portage? (which may be difficult on a Debian-based system?)

Answer (score 0):

So I tried Portage... Installing Portage on a non-Gentoo-based system is much easier than I thought!

They have a port named [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/). I followed the [bootstrapping guide](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/bootstrap-solaris.xml) and it worked flawlessly (almost, except that I need to clear `MAKEFLAGS=-j` for `groff-1.21` to build). It did take a lot of time to build, though.

The greatest things about Gentoo Prefix is that I can keep it separate from the system's package manager and it doesn't require root privilege. I played with the `USE` flags and `CFLAGS` a little bit and the build process seems to be very flexible.

Comment: I came across this while cleaning up my own low score/bad answers from way back. Your answer is definately better than mine, so mind selecting it as such? ;p

Comment: Is this going to get me a pile of deb packages when it's done? The quick skim of the guide seems to be for Gentoo Prefix itself and I'm trying to just rebuild some more complex software.